# Preload UIWebView from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I currently have a LaunchScreen and a UIWebView that loads a web page.

Everything works correctly, the LaunchScreen shows a splash page until the AppDelegate returns from **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**. Then the UIViewController (My Only View Controller) loads.

However, I am loading a url inside viewDidLoad, and you can see a noticeable lag between when the view loads and when the page actually loads.

I was wondering if there is a way to either keep the LaunchScreen open until the UIWebView is fully loaded, or somehow pre-load UIWebView so when the LaunchScreen disappears, the UIWebView is already fully loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Using Xcode 6**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have your view controller show image view with same image as the launch image by default and when the web view is fully loaded then add the web view as a subview or replace the imageview with the webview.